# Composite foreign key that is optional

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, postgresql-9.4

I have a table with a composite foreign key like so:

```
CREATE TABLE a
(
  a1 INTEGER,
  a2 INTEGER,
  a3 INTEGER,
  a4 INTEGER,
  -- other columns
  FOREIGN KEY (a1, a2, a3, a4) REFERENCES b
);
```

The foreign key may or may not exists, therefore `a1` to `a4` may be `NULL`, however if so, they should be `NULL` all at the same time. Is there a better way to specify such an "optional composite foreign key" than to add a (rather verbose) constraint like so?

```
  CHECK ((a1 IS NULL) = (a2 IS NULL) AND 
         (a3 IS NULL) = (a4 IS NULL) AND 
         (a1 IS NULL) = (a3 IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
CREATE TABLE a
(
  a1 INTEGER,
  a2 INTEGER,
  a3 INTEGER,
  a4 INTEGER,
  -- other columns
  FOREIGN KEY (a1, a2, a3, a4) REFERENCES b MATCH FULL
);
```

From the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtable.html):

> A value inserted into the referencing column(s) is matched against the values of 
>   the referenced table and referenced columns using the given match type. There are three match types: MATCH FULL, MATCH PARTIAL, and MATCH SIMPLE (which is the default). MATCH FULL will not allow one column of a multicolumn foreign key to be null unless all foreign key columns are null; if they are all null, the row is not required to have a match in the referenced table.